# Ideal generated by regular sequence is radical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $I=(f_1,...,f_n)$ be an ideal generated by a regular sequence in $k[x_0,...,x_n]$. Then $I=\mathrm{rad}(I)$?

I am reasonably confident this is true but I've been having a lot of trouble coming up with a proof. Is this actually wrong or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think it's wrong. For example, consider $I=(x^2)\subset k[x]$.

Comment: What does "regular sequence" mean? Also the title says "radical" sequence while the question says "regular", which is correct?

Comment: @ shivering soldier, thank you for the counterexample, it seems I may have to rethink something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to be confident since whenever $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is a regular sequence, $x_1^{k_1},\dots,x_n^{k_n}$ is also regular, for every $k_1,\dots,k_n$ positive integers.